# Удалить всё после N-ого символа Python

Tags: python

Нужно удалить всё в строке после 3й запятой

```
str = "['212301303010000', '212301303025000', 'РК84(2123 из 2х)УredALT', '2123-1303010']"
```

пробовал по-разному, после первой легко удалить, а вот после N-ой как-то не выходит.

Comment: покажите пожалуйста как вы удаляли после первой запятой.

Comment: вот так str2 = str.partition(',')[0]

Comment: Применив `string.find(value, start, end)` три раза с обновлением start, найдём позицию третьей запятой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

как вариант:

```
str_ = "['212301303010000', '212301303025000', 'РК84(2123 из 2х)УredALT', '2123-1303010']"

print(','.join(str_.split(',')[:3]) + ']')
```

Comment: Так проще всего конечно. И понятнее

Comment: @CrazyElf Проще всего у меня. Но ненадежно ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Но очень не секурно, да ))

Comment: у меня эта строка из json. Структура всегда будет одинаковая. Что лучше использовать это или Eval?

Comment: @АндрейИванов Если всегда такая, то можно и евал, но это лучше.

Answer (score 4):

Можно распарсить строку через [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) и вытащить нужные элементы.

Пример:

```
import ast

text = "['212301303010000', '212301303025000', 'РК84(2123 из 2х)УredALT', '2123-1303010']"
data = ast.literal_eval(text)
print(data[:3])
# ['212301303010000', '212301303025000', 'РК84(2123 из 2х)УredALT']
```

Answer (score 1):

Удаление всего после 3 запятой:

```
import re

s = "['212301303010000', '212301303025000', 'РК84(2123 из 2х)УredALT', '2123-1303010']"
print(re.sub('([\s\S]+?,)([\s\S]+?,)([\s\S]+?,)[\s\S]*', '\g<1>\g<2>\g<3>', s))
```

Comment: а без регулярок не получится?

Comment: @АндрейИванов если будет более точная спецификация строки, то можно

Answer (score 1):

## Eval is evil.

Использовать `eval` можно только, если вы уверены, что строка содержит правильный питоный код.

```
str_ = "['212301303010000', '212301303025000', 'РК84(2123 из 2х)УredALT', '2123-1303010']"
print(eval(str_)[:3])
```

*Совет: не называйте переменные по именам функций, иначе вы их больше не сможете использовать в коде. По-английски это будет проще: Don't shadow built-ins!*

Comment: Или просто используйте `ast`: `import ast` `ast.literal_eval("['212301303010000', '212301303025000', 'РК84(2123 из 2х)УredALT', '2123-1303010']")`

Comment: @gil9red О! Точно, напишите ответом, заплюсуем ;)